# How does Eigen prevent generating temporary objects?

Tags: c++, eigen

In eigen documentation under the title [why its interesting](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicInsideEigenExample.html) there is an example mentioning how eigen works. The example is

```
#include<Eigen/Core>
int main()
{
  int size = 50;
  // VectorXf is a vector of floats, with dynamic size.
  Eigen::VectorXf u(size), v(size), w(size);
  u = v + w;
}
```

In the doc says, normally due to the design architecture of C++ the above operation would be done using a temporary.

```
VectorXf tmp = v + w;
VectorXf u = tmp;
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) tmp[i] = v[i] + w[i];
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) u[i] = tmp[i];
```

As we can see, due to the temporary object we would need one more loop. But eigen prevent generating this extra loop by not generating this temporary object. So just one loop is enough for this operation.

```
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) u[i] = v[i] + w[i];
```

Although they explained how this matrix sum works but I could not understand it. It would be nice if someone could explain it in simple words.

Comment: It uses a technique called *expression templates*; the result of `v + w` is not actually a vector, but the equivaent of instruction "they want to do v + w". Then , only when the result is actually assigned to a vector, does the calculation occur and so the calcuation can proceed with full knowledge of the whole expression, and thereby avoid temporaries.   If you write `auto&& x = v + w;` you may observe this

Comment: From a quick glance at the documentation, it looks like Eigen uses a technique called "expression templates".  Just do a Google search for this term, there are lots of pages giving nice explanations.

Answer (score 0):

The actual implementation of expression templates inside Eigen is quite complicated thus the description can't be "dumbed down" much. If you are just interested in the concept of expression templates, have a look at the  [corresponding wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expression_templates).
Also read the referenced links/books if you are interested in more details.